# The required column 'int_CommodityPriceId' does not exist in the results. linq to sql

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
public IEnumerable<CommodityPrice> GetAllTimeFrameDaily()
    {
        return _dbprice.ExecuteQuery<CommodityPrice>("SELECT MIN(CommodityPrice.dtm_Date),MAX(CommodityPrice.dtm_Date) FROM CommodityPrice WHERE (CommodityPrice.int_FrequencyId = 1) and int_MarketLocationId in (SELECT [int_LocationId] FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId=4  and int_ParentLocationId in (SELECT [int_LocationId] FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId=2 and int_ParentLocationId in (SELECT int_LocationId FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId = 1 and vcr_LocationEn='Pakistan')))");
    }
```

i am getting this error `The required column 'int_CommodityPriceId' does not exist in the results.` any idea why it is doing this. (my dbml file do have the CommodityPriceId column). i am using linq to sql and vs 2010.running it in running file in sql server

```
commodityprice

int_CommodityPriceId bigint Unchecked
int_CommodityId bigint  Checked
int_SourcesId   int Checked
int_MarketLocationId    int Checked
int_FrequencyId int Checked
flt_Price   float   Checked
flt_PriceUSD    float   Checked
```

Comment: what does `CommodityPrice` look like? But the message *itself* is correct - indeed, `int_CommodityPriceId` does not exist in the results - in fact, NONE of the result columns have names....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is attempting to assign the results to a `CommodityPrice` entity. 
In order to do this, it needs to return all of the columns defined in the `CommodityPrice` entity column properties.. Your query doesn't return ANY of them..

If you just want to return these 2 fields, you'll need a new entity containing just 2 date fields..

```
TimeFrame
dte_CommodityPriceMinDate  datetime  Unchecked
dte_CommodityPriceMaxDate  datetime  Checked
```

and the query should populate this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeFrame> GetAllTimeFrameDaily()
    {
        return _dbprice.ExecuteQuery<TimeFrame>("SELECT MIN(CommodityPrice.dtm_Date) AS dte_CommodityPriceMinDate ,MAX(CommodityPrice.dtm_Date) AS dte_CommodityPriceMaxDate FROM CommodityPrice WHERE (CommodityPrice.int_FrequencyId = 1) and int_MarketLocationId in (SELECT [int_LocationId] FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId=4  and int_ParentLocationId in (SELECT [int_LocationId] FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId=2 and int_ParentLocationId in (SELECT int_LocationId FROM [Location] where int_LocationTypeId = 1 and vcr_LocationEn='Pakistan')))");
    }
```